# `set -e` inside a bash function

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-functions

Does `set -e` behave differently here

```
set -e;

function foo {

}
```

vs.

```
function foo {
  set -e;

}
```

does `set -e` belong inside functions? Does `set -e` declared outside of functions, affect "nested" functions inside a shell file? What about the inverse? Should we call `local set -e` lol?

Comment: My advise ([and many's](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)): don't use `set -e` in a script complex enough as to need functions. Do proper error handling instead.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `set -e` was never supposed to be a replacement for error handling but a safeguard to avoid catastrophic failures if handling error has been overlooked and continuing executing a script after a command failed can easily have crazy consequences, like massive loss of data.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solution to avoid any headaches:

```
function foo {
  (
       set -e;
  )
}
```

(Just use a subshell). Sometimes to make it both confusing and pretty, I do this:

```
 function foo {(
      set -e;
      # the rest goes here
  )}
```

Comment: Actually `{( ... )}` is not required. If you want a function to run in a subshell, just declare it as `foo( ) ( ... code ... )`. This is perfectly valid according to POSIX standard. Function bodies can either be enclosed in `{ ... }` or `( ... )`, depending if you want to run it in the same shell or in a subshell.

Answer (score 13):

*Note: the statements here apply to Bash version 4.0.35 and up. Implementations of `set -e` [vary wildly among different shells/versions](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/). Follow [Stéphane's advice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405382/set-e-inside-a-bash-function/405422#comment725131_405422) and don't use `set -e`.*

`man bash` in the Shell Builtin Commands/`set` section explains things pretty well though the text is a little dense and requires a bit of focus. To your specific questions the answers are:

- *Does `set -e` behave different here...vs..* - Depends on what you mean by "differently" but I suspect you'd consider the answer "no"...there are no tricky scoping rules. It acts quite linearlly.
- *Does set -e belong inside functions?* - Perfectly valid.
- *Does set -e declared outside of functions, affect "nested" functions inside a shell file?* - Yes
- *What about the inverse?* - `set -e` in a function and then encounter a non-zero status after return? Yes, this will exit.

Comment: There are complex rules that differ between versions. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 and linked pages for details. Best to stay away from `set -e`.

Comment: will `set -e` inside a function affect the whole shell? Because this question - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407385/any-command-in-my-terminal-that-exits-with-non-zero-code-closes-my-terminal-wind

Comment: Yes, that's what the fourth bullet indicates. Functions aren't isolated environments (discounting `local` vars). (If you ever use `set -x` to debug and put it in a function you'll see this in action.) Again, I've only tested with Bash 4.4... earlier (much earlier?) versions may have different behavior.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas But that's only because bash is a broken mess. The POSIX standard is very clear on this and demands that the the flag does propagate to subshells. Here's an example from the POSIX standard: `set -e; (false; echo one) | cat; echo two` In this code the standard demands that `one` must not be printed and the subshell must exit. Any shell showing different behavior is not POSIX conform.