# Any command in my terminal that exits with non-zero code closes my terminal window

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal, bashrc

At first this was a bit funny, like playing "Bash Roulette"
...but now it's getting old lol

*Any command in my terminal that exits with non-zero code closes my terminal window*

I was told that perhaps I have `set -e` set in some bash script somewhere that my terminal sources.

I have checked `.bash_profile` / `.bashrc` / `.profile` and it doesn't look like `set -e` is in there.

Would there be any other obvious culprits?

Comment: Execute a `set +e`, does it repair the problem? If so, which I assume, then you need to keep looking for that `set -e`. It could be in the global versions of these files under `/etc`, or in any other script sourced from them. Move your config files away, if the problem is fixed then add back the lines in smaller chunks to see where it breaks.

Comment: `PS4=' ${BASH_SOURCE}:$LINENO: ' bash -lixc true |& grep -e set -e trap` could be informative.

Comment: You can inspect the set of currently enabled shell flags with the special variable `-` like so: `echo $-`.

Comment: What if `set +e` does not fix the problem?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Alright, so indeed, it was a wayward `set -e` that caused my trouble.

The way I found the `set -e` was using `bash -lx`

The best thing to do would be to use:

`bash -lx > lx.log 2>&1`

then open that log file and do a search for `set`...

once you find that wayward `set -e` you can remove that line and your problem should be gone! (Machine restart might be a good idea tho).

In my case, the `set -e` was in a file that .bash_profile sources, but the line was not in .bash_profile itself.

Comment: Things that are safe to `source` in your shell is a much smaller set than just "random shell scripts".  `-e` can be useful in actual scripts, for dumb error checking.  (Or to make sure you didn't *forget* to error-check anything.)

Comment: Apparently that's case...i wish there was something like `global set -e` so that `set -e` only affects the containing script

Comment: @AlexanderMills, to do that, you could check `$-` to check for the flag in the inner script and restore its state at the end, or just reset it at the main script if you know you have sourced scripts that would set it

Comment: So I guess `local set -e` could only be used in a bash function?

Answer (score 14):

If you just want to solve the problem, include `set +e` in your `.bashrc` — at the *end.*

You can go digging—there are a lot of other places where a `set -e` might be—but that will take care of the lot.

If, however, the `set -e` is part of your `$PROMPT_COMMAND` then the above will not work.  Try `printf '%s\n' "$PROMPT_COMMAND"` and see what's in it.

Comment: on my machine, when I open a terminal, `printf '%s\n' "$PROMPT_COMMAND"` yields just whitespace, nothing there

Comment: @AlexanderMills, then that's not what your problem is.  One common use for `$PROMPT_COMMAND` is to update the terminal tab name or window name; MacOS X and Ubuntu both do this.  See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/220641/151730 for data on this for Mac.

Comment: I found an answer to the problem and added my own answer, `set +e` didn't work, perhaps because it was *before* the `set -e` call in my sourced bash files.

Comment: @AlexanderMills, yes, I thought that was implicit.  I meant to *append* `set +e` to your `.bashrc`, not put it in at the start.  I've made that explicit in my answer now.  Good that you found the source!

Comment: Yeah, `set +e` is just a band-aid obviously, but you stated that

Comment: Note that even if `set +e` is appended to `.bashrc` there might still be a command in between (after `set -e` is called) that causes an early exit from non zero return status.

Comment: @JohnB yes, but that wouldn't give you "bash roulette" as described.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the `set -e` was not in any of my bash startups and appending `set +e` to my `.bashrc` was not fixing it.

It turns out the `set -e` was in a bash script that I frequently run for my project, and I was running that script using `. ./my-dev-script.sh` so that it would [honor my bash aliases](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/614357/392855).

What I didn't realize is running it with that extra `.` in front was also causing the bash options in the script to carry over into all my regular terminal sessions.

I need a new solution for running a bash script that honors my personal bash aliases, but at least I found the source of the rogue `set -e`. Just running it normally with `./my-dev-script.sh` prevents the frustrating "Bash Roulette" scenario.